# Applying Matlab Images Filter On RGB Images

Tags: matlab, plot, image-editing, image-effects

i have the following Matlab code to manipulate two images, gray scale image, and `RGB` image.
The point is to apply `Average`,`Gaussian`, and `Laplacian` filters on both images.

```
%%Clear
clear
clc
%%Reading images
gray=imread('cameraman.tif')
[gray_table gray_map]=gray2ind(gray,256)
rgb=imread('peppers.png')
[rgb_table rgb_map]=rgb2ind(rgb,256)
%%Creating filters
average=fspecial('average',3)
gaussian=fspecial('gaussian',3,0.5)
laplacian=fspecial('laplacian',0.9)
%%Applying filters
average_filterd_gray_table=imfilter(gray_table,average)
gaussian_filterd_gray_table=imfilter(gray_table,gaussian)
laplacian_filterd_gray_table=imfilter(gray_table,laplacian)
average_filterd_rgb_table=imfilter(rgb_table,average)
gaussian_filterd_rgb_table=imfilter(rgb_table,gaussian)
laplacian_filterd_rgb_table=imfilter(rgb_table,laplacian)
%%view
figure
subplot(1,4,1),imshow(gray_table,gray_map),title('Original Indexed Gray')
subplot(1,4,2),imshow(average_filterd_gray_table,gray_map),title('Average Filtered Indexed Gray')
subplot(1,4,3),imshow(gaussian_filterd_gray_table,gray_map),title('Gaussian Filtered Indexed Gray')
subplot(1,4,4),imshow(laplacian_filterd_gray_table,gray_map),title('Laplacian Filtered Indexed Gray')
figure
subplot(1,4,1),imshow(rgb_table,rgb_map),title('Original Indexed RGB')
subplot(1,4,2),imshow(average_filterd_rgb_table,rgb_map),title('Average Filtered Indexed RGB')
subplot(1,4,3),imshow(gaussian_filterd_rgb_table,rgb_map),title('Gaussian Filtered Indexed RGB')
subplot(1,4,4),imshow(laplacian_filterd_rgb_table,rgb_map),title('Laplacian Filtered Indexed RGB')
```

The code is working fine for the gray scale image. but on RGB image it just gives a distorted result. How to fix that?

Comment: Have you tried applyng the filters to each channel separately? Or else to each HSV channel separately? Or just the "V" channel of HSV perhaps

Comment: @Dan could you please code it ?

Comment: so does any of the proposed answer helped you? If so please accept one so the thread is closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the doc for `rgb2ind` (click [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html)):

when loading a rgb image like so:

`[X,map] = rgb2ind(RGB,n)`, the doc says:

> Note   The values in the resultant image X are indexes into the
>   colormap map and should not be used in mathematical processing, such
>   as filtering operations.

So you might be better off filtering directly the RGB images. The following works fine:

```
clear
clc
close all

RGBImage = imread('peppers.png');

average = fspecial('average',3);
gaussian=fspecial('gaussian',3,0.5);
laplacian=fspecial('laplacian',0.9);

RGB_Average = imfilter(RGBImage,average);
RGB_Gaussian= imfilter(RGBImage,gaussian);
RGB_Laplacian = imfilter(RGBImage,laplacian);

figure;
subplot(2,2,1)
imshow(RGBImage)
title('Original')

subplot(2,2,2)
imshow(RGB_Average)
title('Average')

subplot(2,2,3)
imshow(RGB_Gaussian)
title('Gaussian')

subplot(2,2,4)
imshow(RGB_Laplacian)
title('Laplacian')
```

which gives this:

[image]

Comment: Ok, but then why it worked fine with an indexed gray scale image ?

Comment: @Djhseen because `gray_table` is the same as `gray` but it's not true for `rgb`.

Comment: Yep, rgb/truecolor lookup tables are in 3D vs in 2D for grayscale images. All values are similar for the 3 dimensions in grayscale (r,g and b) whereas it's not the case for rgb.

Comment: great. If the answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted (check mark at the top left). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you are reading the image in the following way:

```
rgb=imread('peppers.png')
[rgb_table rgb_map]=rgb2ind(rgb,256);
```

With this, you can apply the filter's because the way that you applied made some changes on the image colors:

```
[rgb_table rgb_map]=imread('peppers.png')
average=fspecial('average',3);
gaussian=fspecial('gaussian',3,0.5);
laplacian=fspecial('laplacian',0.9);
average_filterd_rgb_table=imfilter(rgb_table,average);
gaussian_filterd_rgb_table=imfilter(rgb_table,gaussian);
laplacian_filterd_rgb_table=imfilter(rgb_table,laplacian);
subplot(2,2,1),imshow(rgb),title('Original Indexed RGB')
subplot(2,2,2),imshow(average_filterd_rgb_table),title('Average Filtered Indexed RGB')
subplot(2,2,3),imshow(gaussian_filterd_rgb_table),title('Gaussian Filtered Indexed RGB')
subplot(2,2,4),imshow(laplacian_filterd_rgb_table),title('Laplacian Filtered Indexed RGB')
```

This is the image I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use `gray2ind` and `rgb2ind`, see if this works.

```
gray=imread('cameraman.tif');
rgb=imread('peppers.png');
%%Creating filters
average=fspecial('average',3);
gaussian=fspecial('gaussian',3,0.5);
laplacian=fspecial('laplacian',0.9);
%%Applying filters
average_filterd_gray=imfilter(gray,average);
gaussian_filterd_gray=imfilter(gray,gaussian);
laplacian_filterd_gray=imfilter(gray,laplacian);
average_filterd_rgb=imfilter(rgb,average);
gaussian_filterd_rgb=imfilter(rgb,gaussian);
laplacian_filterd_rgb=imfilter(rgb,laplacian);
%%view
figure
subplot(2,2,1),imshow(gray),title('Original Indexed Gray')
subplot(2,2,2),imshow(average_filterd_gray),title('Average Filtered Indexed Gray')
subplot(2,2,3),imshow(gaussian_filterd_gray),title('Gaussian Filtered Indexed Gray')
subplot(2,2,4),imshow(laplacian_filterd_gray),title('Laplacian Filtered Indexed Gray')
figure
subplot(2,2,1),imshow(rgb),title('Original Indexed RGB')
subplot(2,2,2),imshow(average_filterd_rgb),title('Average Filtered Indexed RGB')
subplot(2,2,3),imshow(gaussian_filterd_rgb),title('Gaussian Filtered Indexed RGB')
subplot(2,2,4),imshow(laplacian_filterd_rgb),title('Laplacian Filtered Indexed RGB')
```